# how to write several variables into an array?

Tags: javascript

I want to write several variables into an array for one call to the "addLetter" method, "push" and "concat" does not work

```js
function Team(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.letters = [];
}
Team.prototype.addLetter = function (letter) {
    this.letters.push(letter).join('\n');
};
Team.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "Name of team - " + this.name +  '\n' +"ltters : " + this.letters;
};
var a = 's';
b='g';
v='d';
var team1 =  new Team('letters');
team1.addLetter(a,b,v);
console.log(team1.toString());
```

Comment: Well, you never defined `addMember`, so that's causing an error.

Comment: Where's `addMember` declaration?

Comment: sorr I did not change the name

Comment: Also your toString-function tries to log members instead of letters.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns an integer rather than an array.

Comment: addLetter() is defined with one arg but you call it with 3.  Think you need to use the Arguments object in addLetter().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using ES6:

```
Team.prototype.addLetter = function() {
    this.letters.push(...arguments);
};
```

With older syntax:

```
Team.prototype.addLetter = function() {
    this.letters.push.apply(this.letters.push, arguments);
};
```

JavaScript allows any number of arguments to be passed to any function. All of these arguments are accessible via the `arguments` variable within the function, which is an array-like object, containing all arguments in the order they were passed.